# Rails 6 monads pattern matching to fetch only success/failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, monads

Is there any build in or some nifty way to fetch only Success or Failure results from array of monad results?

e.g.

```
state
=> [Failure("12345 Product code is not valid"), Success("eiowruqoiu Backbone Product created")]
```

where

```
state[0].class
=> Dry::Monads::Result::Failure
state[1].class
=> Dry::Monads::Result::Success
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
state.grep(Dry::Monads::Result::Failure)
state.grep(Dry::Monads::Result::Success)
```

or

```
state.select { |s| s.is_a?(Dry::Monads::Result::Failure) }
state.select { |s| s.is_a?(Dry::Monads::Result::Success) }
```

or using `success?` / `failure?` monads methods

```
state.select(&:success?)
state.select(&:failure?)
```

```
state.reject(&:success?)
state.reject(&:failure?)
```